# Why you need to provide service in module

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular app and I have a module and a service class that is holding all my needed functions. I am importing the service class in my component and I use it as needed. Now I see that I need to include it into the module providers. But why is this needed? I am already using it as it is and including it into the module providers do not change nothing in the way I am using it. I still need to import it and declare an instance of it in the component. What is the difference?

Comment: Can you show us the service (at least the @Injectable() decorator declaration) and the module (the relevant parts only)?

Comment: It's used for dependency injection, this instruction will help you create a single instance for the service in the module !

Comment: You can check official docs for more details : https://angular.io/guide/providers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service need to be declare in the module provider to tell Angular to include the service class in your module.
When you project is more complex, you will have more modules in a single project. So you will want to import only the relevant code into your module. Thus you can choose only a specific set of services you want to in the providers.

Else you can also declare the service as root service. By doing sos, you can use the service everywhere within your project without declaring in the provider.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my question if someone else is wondering the same. The reason the services to work without declaring them in providers is because the Injectable that Angular adds automatically when the services is created with ng generate service:

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
```

I suppose if it is not there then the providing will be necessary.

Comment: Providing will always necessary, here also you are providing in the root. One more advantage of this approach, you services will be available across all module, components without the need of import and provide specifically. Sometime we ended up adding same import statement and provider across different modules for the same service.